# -bash: /etc/profile: Input/output error

Tags: partitioning, bash, ssh, hard-drive, lubuntu

When I was trying to connect ssh to my remote machine after ssh and enter password it give **-bash: /etc/profile: Input/output error** some time but after hard reboot I'm able to ssh my remote machine is there any hardware issue or else and how to permanent resolve this issue

Comment: Did you read your machine logs? look in your `/etc/profile` file looking for any errors? (it's text so errors will be easy to view).  We don't know your system (OS, release, hardware etc), you've implied it's a desktop (thus the Lubuntu tag) but we don't know release so cannot know whether *some time* is reasonable, being limited to what you provide, but I'd look in system logs for clues (you didn't provide release details so this is vague, `dmesg`, `journalctl` etc)

Comment: thanks for your reply @guiverc but I'm not getting any log file  /etc/profile, /etc/profile file something look like some script file

Comment: I was talking about the system logfiles for your still *unstated* release.  Yes the file is "*system‐wide  .profile file for the Bourne shell*" ; but given the error message for your *unstated* release specifically mentions that file; I'd check it's valid like I said prior comment.